# I'm struggling to display indices as superscript in WPF. Some characters coming out as superscript when they shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf, indices, typography

I'm trying to build a WPF application to assist with some math revision and I'm having an issue with displaying the index values as superscript. I am trying to format the generated question strings to the desired output from the codebehind.  I was originally trying to display the generated questions simply as strings in a textblock. (Marking index values with a '#' at the start and end of each value in the inputted string.)

```
        private char ConvertSingleToSuperscript(char input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case '0':
                return '⁰';
            case '1':
                return '¹';
            case '2':
                return '²';
            case '3':
                return '³';
            case '4':
                return '⁴';
            case '5':
                return '⁵';
            case '6':
                return '6';
            case '7':
                return '⁷';
            case '8':
                return '⁸';
            case '9':
                return '⁹';
            case '+':
                return '⁺';
            case '-':
                return '⁻';
            case '=':
                return '⁼';
            case '/':
                return char.Parse(char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x2044));
            default:
                throw new Exception("Incorrect character entered as superscript, change entered indice value.");
        }
    }

 public string ProcessSuperscript(string input)
    {
        char[] tempArray = input.ToCharArray();
        string outputString = "";
        bool processingIndice = false;
        foreach(char c in tempArray)
        {
            if(c == '#')
            {
                processingIndice = !processingIndice;
            }
            if (processingIndice)
            {
                outputString += ConvertSingleToSuperscript(c);
            }
            else
            {
                outputString += c;
            }
        }
        return outputString;
    }
```

Using this, or having my 'ConvertSingleToSuperScript' method return char values generated through the relevant superscript unicode would always return string where 1, 2, and 3 are displayed as superscript items and the remainder would all return text the same size as the rest of the 'non-indice' values in the string.

Recently I have instead tried using textblock inline runs to achieve the same result:

```
        private void FormatQuestionSuperScriptDisplay(TextBlock displayBlock, string variableText)
    {
        char[] tempArray = variableText.ToCharArray();
        string processString = "";
        bool processingIndice = false;
        foreach (char c in tempArray)
        {
            if (c == '#')
            {
                if (!processingIndice)
                {
                    displayBlock.Inlines.Add(processString);
                    Console.WriteLine(processString + " as normal");
                }
                else
                {
                    displayBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(processString) { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript });
                    Console.WriteLine(processString + " as indice.");
                }
                processString = "";
                processingIndice = !processingIndice;
                continue;
            }
            processString += c;
        }
        displayBlock.Inlines.Add(processString);
    }
}
```

I must have messed up here somewhere as well as now my output will come out as in the image below from the string: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  12#32# 15#4589# test"

[For those unable to see the image the characters for 'i' and 'n' are displayed as superscript characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tSHf.png)

One more question I have is that all the numerical values once ran through the Inlines.Add() method are processed as superscript characters as well, how can process them (I'm not sure what the correct term is so I'll say) at a normal size matching the rest of the string?

Any assistance or pointers on what I should be reading up on would be mega helpful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first code works if you just change the second `if` to a `else if` since you don't want to process the # as a superscript element.  Or you could just add a `continue;` at the end of the `if(c == '#')`.  And you need to fix `ConvertSingleToSuperscript` to map the 6 to the correct character.

Comment: Apologies, you're absolutely right. I forgot to include the 'continue' statement. Now however, both methods produce the same output and 'i' and 'n' characters still display as superscript. Any ideas on why that is?

Thanks again

Comment: When I tried the code I got "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 12³² 15⁴⁵⁸⁹ test" so I'm not sure how you're getting the i and n as superscript.

Comment: Oh man, that's strange I must have done something strange elsewhere in my code. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's work for me.
Check function ProcessSuperscript.

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace SuperScript
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FormatQuestionSuperScriptDisplay(tbText, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 12#32# 15#4589# test");
        }

        private char ConvertSingleToSuperscript(char input)
        {
            switch (input)
            {
                case '0':
                    return '⁰';
                case '1':
                    return '¹';
                case '2':
                    return '²';
                case '3':
                    return '³';
                case '4':
                    return '⁴';
                case '5':
                    return '⁵';
                case '6':
                    return '6';
                case '7':
                    return '⁷';
                case '8':
                    return '⁸';
                case '9':
                    return '⁹';
                case '+':
                    return '⁺';
                case '-':
                    return '⁻';
                case '=':
                    return '⁼';
                case '/':
                    return char.Parse(char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x2044));
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Incorrect character entered as superscript, change entered indice value.");
            }
        }

        public string ProcessSuperscript(string input)
        {
            char[] tempArray = input.ToCharArray();
            string outputString = "";
            bool processingIndice = false;
            foreach (char c in tempArray)
            {
                if (c == '#')
                {
                    processingIndice = !processingIndice;
                    continue; //<- This code added.
                }
                if (processingIndice)
                {
                    outputString += ConvertSingleToSuperscript(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    outputString += c;
                }
            }
            return outputString;
        }

        private void FormatQuestionSuperScriptDisplay(TextBlock displayBlock, string variableText)
        {
            char[] tempArray = variableText.ToCharArray();
            string processString = "";
            bool processingIndice = false;
            foreach (char c in tempArray)
            {
                if (c == '#')
                {
                    if (!processingIndice)
                    {
                        displayBlock.Inlines.Add(processString);
                        Console.WriteLine(processString + " as normal");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        displayBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(processString) { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript });
                        Console.WriteLine(processString + " as indice.");
                    }
                    processString = "";
                    processingIndice = !processingIndice;
                    continue;
                }
                processString += c;
            }
            displayBlock.Inlines.Add(processString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for this. You're absolutely right that fixed one of the described issues. Following this fix both of my methods produced the same result with 'i' and 'n' displaying as superscript for some reason. 

I realised I stupidly still had a 'Typography.Variants= "Superscript" property on my textblock in the xaml file from a previous attempt. 

Thanks for your help!